# Threads continue when activity is restarted

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a Simple Main Activity, that contains a thread to update the time and display it onto the UI. Here it is:

```
        final Runnable runnableTime = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            {
                Date d = new Date();
                CharSequence timeString = DateFormat.format(
                        "hh: mm: ss -- d/MM/yyyy ", d.getTime());
                infoEntries.get(0).setDetails((String) timeString);
                c2_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println(timeString);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnableTime);
```

Now My problem is that when i restart the activity using this method:

```
    public void restart() {
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

The activity restarts just fine, but i now have 2 of the same threads running in the background and the time is no longer being updated on the UI.

I have tried creating my own Runnable that extends Runnable for me to be able to terminate the runnable on restart. But that only caused more issues.

Ive overriden these methods in this fashion:

```
    public void restart() {
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    handler.post(runnableTime);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(null);
}
```

Here is the time item that is called in the on create method and also inside of teh timer ^ :

```
        Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence timeString = DateFormat.format("hh: mm: ss -- d/MM/yyyy ",
            d.getTime());

    infoEntries.add(new ConsoleItem((String) timeString));
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you in advance for you time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time is not updating in the UI because you lost the reference to the UI. Also it will be better to make a while loop with a sleep() inside the run method, to handle time progress, and exit the while loop on activity onPause(). Like example it could be

```
boolean running = false;
    while (running) {
        // TODO do your stuff
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

before to start counting call

```
running=true;
```

and in activity onPause()

```
running=false;
```

this way you will handle when to start the runnable and it will stop on activity pause/

Comment: This look a lot cleaner and easier to understand. But im not sure how to implement the on pause. Because its still not updating it correctly. Now the time never updates.

Comment: Do you have a ListView or something like this?
in your activity you have to override the onPause() method of the Activity class, there just add the running=false line just after super.onPause().

Comment: Yes the Time is inside a list View.

Comment: Each row has it's time, or you have only one row,first one like header, with the time? Also when starting the runnable use activity.runOnUiThread(), so you could invalidate the views from the runnable.

Comment: I have one row which displays the time ill add it to the question :)

Comment: if you have just 1 row with the time, than it will be better to set it like listHeader and add the layout to it, and in the runnable invalidate the view, and not the adapter, this will make your listview to be more smooth.

Comment: Awesome thank you ill do that :) . But it still is running two threads after i restart the application.

Comment: your code shoud be like this

in onCreate() you should initialise the view and all it's components;
in onResume you should set running=true, and call runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){....}
in onPause you should set running=false;

in such a way will always have only one runnable running.

Comment: runnign should be set to true at first though. in teh on create :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have any threads (only ui thread).
Second, if you start something you should stop it somewhere.

So, move this `handler.post(runnableTime);` to Activity's onResume method, and add `handler.removeCallbacks(runnableTime);` to Activity's on Pause method.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Iv'e added the two methods: OnPause and on create, but i cant do: handler.remove it gives me an error and asks me to parse it to a (bundle).

Comment: I've made a typo ) it should be removeCallbacks )

Comment: i moved it to the onResume method, but now it doesnt run at all :/ Ill update teh question.

Answer (score 0):

According to @blackbelt answer

in your activity override the onPause method

```
@override
public void onPause()
{
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnableTime );
}
```